# Calculate the areas of two holes found in a MRI image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to calculate the areas of two holes found in a MRI image? I tried using imellipse and imfreehand. But i could not find the area for both the holes. It was just one at a time. How can i know the areas of both the holes?

Image:

[image]

Comment: You could do it with `imfreehand` within a script, or you might want to use `regioprops`. Can you provide an image to work with?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qe9utm64pktfur/test.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the image, Can you outline where are the holes you are referring to? thanks!

Comment: the holes which are present in the left hemisphere of the brain.

Comment: Ok I see them. So you don't need a method that will automatically detect the holes? Would a GUI with a couple buttons that lets you select them manually be fine?

Comment: yae that will be good enough for me..but i also must output the area of the two holes and the distance between them.

Comment: Alright I just posted an elaborate answer haha hope this is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a GUI which does what you need. The longest part is to set up the actual GUI but the rest is quite straightforward. I commented the code. As you will see, the area is automatically calculated after you finish tracing each region. I put an edit box to enter the factor converting pixels to um to get an actual distance...that's easy to apply to the calculation.

So in the GUI there are 2 pushbuttons:

1) Trace hole is used to manually trace a hole on the image. Once you have 2 holes, you can press the 2nd pushbutton which

2) calculates the centroids of the points and display them in a new figure. The distance between the points (in pixels) is also computed. Note that it could be generalized for more than 2 points but I'll leave that up to you.

Here is the code with screenshots:

```
function HoleBrain(~)

clc
clear
close all

%// Set up GUI and components
hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 800 800],'Units','Pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[80,100,650,650]);
handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','Push','Position',[30 700 90 40],'String','Trace hole','Callback',@(s,e) DrawHoleCallback);

handles.NumHolesTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[30 670 90 20],'String', '# holes','BackgroundColor',[.6 .6 .6]);
handles.NumHolesDisp = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[30 640 90 20],'String', '0');

handles.HoleIDTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[20 610 40 20],'String', 'Hole','BackgroundColor',[.6 .6 .6]);
handles.HoleID = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[20 540 40 80],'String', '');

handles.AreaTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[70 610 60 20],'String', 'Area','BackgroundColor',[.6 .6 .6]);
handles.Area = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[70 540 60 80],'String', '');

handles.PixToMicron = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[40 500 60 20],'String', 'um/pixel','BackgroundColor',[.6 .6 .6]);
handles.PixToMicronEdit = uicontrol('Style','edit','Position',[40 470 60 20],'String', '');

handles.CentroidButton = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[10 430 120 20],'String', 'Measure centroids','Callback',@(s,e) MeasureCentroidsCallback,'BackgroundColor',[.1 .4 .9],'FontSize',12);

handles.DistanceTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[40 400 60 20],'String','Distance','BackgroundColor',[.6 .6 .6]);
handles.DistanceText = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[40 370 60 20],'String','');

Im = imread('BrainMRI.jpg');

%// Get the size of the image
[handles.h,handles.w,~] = size(Im);

%// Crop the image to get larger field of view of the region to select.
handles.NewIm = Im(round(handles.h/4):round(3*handles.h/4),round(1):round(handles.w/2),:);
handles.NewSize = [size(handles.NewIm,1) size(handles.NewIm,2)];
imshow(handles.NewIm,'InitialMagnification',1000)

%// Set up counter to count # of holes traced.
handles.HoleCounter = 0;

guidata(hFigure,handles);

%// Callback of the pushbutton. Press it to start tracing a hole.
    function DrawHoleCallback(~)
        handles = guidata(hFigure);

        %// Counter
        handles.HoleCounter = handles.HoleCounter + 1;

        hHand = imfreehand(gca);

        %// Store the mask created by the trace. Important! 
        handles.maskHand{handles.HoleCounter} = createMask(hHand);

        %// Calculate/display the area of the region/hole. In pixel units!
        outI = uint8(handles.maskHand{handles.HoleCounter}).*handles.NewIm(:,:,1);

        handles.AreaPixels(handles.HoleCounter) = sum(outI(:));

        A = handles.AreaPixels;

        set(handles.NumHolesDisp,'String',num2str(handles.HoleCounter));

        set(handles.HoleID,'String',num2str(transpose(1:handles.HoleCounter)));
        set(handles.Area,'String',num2str(A(:)));

        %// Update guidata.
        guidata(hFigure,handles);
    end

%// Used to detect centroids and measure the distance between the holes.
    function MeasureCentroidsCallback(~)

        handles = guidata(hFigure);

        %// Create new logical image to actually find centroid and display them.
        ImBW = false(handles.NewSize(1),handles.NewSize(2));

        for k = 1:handles.HoleCounter            
            ImBW((handles.maskHand{k})) = 1;
        end

        %// Get coordinates
        S = regionprops(ImBW,'Centroid');
        CentroidCoord = vertcat(S.Centroid);

        %// Create new figure to display new image
        figure('Position',[300 300 800 800],'Units','Pixels');
        axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[80,100,650,650]);

        imshow(handles.NewIm,'InitialMagnification',1000)
        hold on
        for k = 1:numel(S)            
            scatter(S(k).Centroid(:,1), S(k).Centroid(:,2),30,'filled');
        end

        %//Trace line to connect points
        line([CentroidCoord(1,1) CentroidCoord(2,1)],[CentroidCoord(1,2) CentroidCoord(2,2)],'Color','y','LineStyle','-','LineWidth',2)

        hold off

        %// Measure distance
        Dist = pdist(CentroidCoord,'euclidean');

        %// Display distance
        set(handles.DistanceText,'String',num2str(Dist));

        guidata(hFigure,handles);
    end
end
```

The GUI looks like this:

[image]

After tracing 2 holes:

[image]

And finally after calculating the distance between them:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think [Image Segmenter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-using-the-image-segmenter-app.html?refresh=true) app is exactly what you need. It gives you multiple ways to initialize and refine the segmentation. The app outputs a binary mask representing your regions of interest. After that, you can use the `regionprops` function to measure their area in pixels.

Comment: i used Image Segmenter app but could not refine for the holes under observation. I used region based contour but no success.